# Do I always have to run mix clean then compile after changing config?

Tags: elixir, beam

I'm relatively new to Elixir and I've noticed something strange, I have a config, config.exs

which has a line like

```
config :my_app, myname: "name"
```

When I change the value of the myname key, my app behaves as if the value was still "name" but if I do mix clean then compile my app, it reacts to the new value, I've looked around to see how configuration files are handled but I can't seem to find anything that explains why I have to do a clean for my app to react to the changes.

**EDIT:** This application is part of an umbrella project and I'm changing the config for the app not the umbrella config.exs

Comment: So the value is not changed for you if you just do `mix compile`?

Comment: I just created an umbrella app and I get the new config values if I manually restart `iex -S mix`. I didn't have to do `mix compile` manually. Can you tell what steps exactly you followed when the config change didn't reflect in the app? Were you testing from `iex -S mix`? or something else?

Comment: the value does not change if I just do a mix compile, it will only work after I do mix clean. I was testing from iex -S mix. 

I added a new config key and value to my configuration. I did iex -S mix then ran some code and it was okay. I then changed the value, did iex -S mix again but it was behaving as if the value hadn't changed

Comment: That's strange. This works correctly for me both when I restart `iex -S mix` from root and from `apps/a`. I'm on Elixir 1.4.2. I'm checking the value using `Application.get_all_env(:a)` and it always updates without any manual `mix compile`.

Comment: I've just tried to change the value again without a manual compile and it works, I'm nit sure what was wrong